# MYSQL Multiplication from views

Tags: mysql, math, view, group-by, inner-join

Just need to run this simple math problem from two different views. When It runs it gives me the wrong numbers as the answer. Is it not possible to run a math problem from two views like this?

```
    SELECT FORMAT((alchX.sumofvalue) * (medY.sumofvalue),2) AS 'PowerSum(x+y)'
    FROM alchX
    JOIN medY
    ON medY.area_code = alchX.area_code
    GROUP BY alchX.series_id
```

Here is the SQL FIDDLE http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dd463/2
It runs perfectly fine on Fiddle but on phpMyAdmin I get

```
   PowerSum(x+y)
    10
    20
    15
```

Comment: You didn't specify the data you have - the numbers you are multiplying, nor did you provide what result you get, nor what result you expect. To put it in simple words, where are the numbers and how do you know you are not wrong in your assumption that you're getting the wrong result back? Computers don't lie.

Comment: I am pretty sure it is because MYSQL set the sumofvalue to VARCHAR as default. Since it is in a view. How can I force MYSQL to make this column into a DECIMAL data type?

Comment: If you're pretty sure then that must be it.

Comment: Then just cast to a number in your query https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast

Answer (score 0):

You `GROUP BY` a column but don't use an aggregate function. Therefore, the printed result will be computed from *any* matching pair of rows for the series. Could it be that in your real data on which you operate with phpMyAdmin you have more than one row per series? Or did you want to group by `area_code` instead? You might want to include `*` in the query to see what data gets used as the input for your computation.